# how to do a proper pandas group by, where, sum

Tags: pandas

i am having a hard time using a group by + where to apply a sum to a broader range.

given this code:

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

f = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
fund_id,l_s,val
fund1,L,10
fund1,L,20
fund1,S,30
fund2,L,15
fund2,L,25
fund2,L,35
"""))


# fund total - works as expected
f['fund_total'] = f.groupby('fund_id')['val'].transform(np.sum)
# fund L total - applied only to L rows. 
f['fund_total_l'] = f[f['l_s'] == "L"].groupby('fund_id')['val'].transform(np.sum)
f
```

this code gets me close: 
[image]

numbers are correct, but i would like `fund_total_l` column to show `30` for all rows of fund1 (not just `L`). I want a fund level summary, but sum filtered by the `l_s` column

i know i can do this with multiple steps, but this needs to be a single operation. i can use a separate generic function if that helps.

playground: https://repl.it/repls/UnusualImpeccableDaemons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html), to create `NaN`, these will be ignored in your `sum`:

```
f['val_temp'] = f['val'].where(f['l_s'] == "L")
f['fund_total_l'] = f.groupby('fund_id')['val_temp'].transform('sum')
f = f.drop(columns='val_temp')
```

Or in one line using `assign`:

```
df['fun_total_l'] = (
    f.assign(val_temp=f['val'].where(f['l_s'] == "L"))
    .groupby('fund_id')['val_temp'].transform('sum')
)
```

Another way would be to partly use your solution, but then use `DataFrame.reindex` to get the original index back and then use `ffill` and `bfill` to fill up our `NaN`:

```
f['fund_total_l'] = (
    f[f['l_s'] == "L"]
    .groupby('fund_id')['val']
    .transform('sum')
    .reindex(f.index)
    .ffill()
    .bfill()
)
```

```
  fund_id l_s  val  fund_total_l
0   fund1   L   10          30.0
1   fund1   L   20          30.0
2   fund1   S   30          30.0
3   fund2   L   15          75.0
4   fund2   L   25          75.0
5   fund2   L   35          75.0
```

Comment: i can't use a temporary column. for my needs it needs to be a generic operation that returns a new series. custom external functions are allowed. i guess i could plug it inline ?

Comment: Did you check my second solution? Custom external functions can be really slow. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/9081267)

Comment: Added third solution which also does not create a temp column.

Comment: i like that 2nd one. thanks! just wondering if it could be simplified using something like `np.sum` since it has a `where` parameter?  or maybe put a part of it in a generic func ?

Comment: Hmm, not sure if that would work with `GroupBy.transform`

Comment: You can try something like: `f.assign(boolcol=f['l_s'].eq('L')).groupby('fund_id').transform(lambda x: np.sum(x['val'].to_numpy(), where=x['boolcol']))`

Comment: It's not terribly different, though it's possible to group by a Series that shares the same index. So you can `where` one series, and group by another unmasked Series to get ensure you have non-masked group keys for every row. `f['val'].where(f.l_s.eq('L')).groupby(f.fund_id).transform('sum')`

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a more elegant solution, but I'm not able to broadcast the results back to the individual rows.

Essentially, with a boolean mask of all the "L" rows

```
f.groupby("fund_id").apply(lambda g:sum(g["val"]*(g["l_s"]=="L")))
```

you obtain

```
       fund_id
fund1    30
fund2    75
dtype: int64
```

now we can just merge after using `reset_index` to obtain

```
pd.merge(f, f.groupby("fund_id").apply(lambda g:sum(g["val"]*(g["l_s"]=="L"))).reset_index(), on="fund_id")
```

to obtain

```
  fund_id l_s  val   0
0   fund1   L   10  30
1   fund1   L   20  30
2   fund1   S   30  30
3   fund2   L   15  75
4   fund2   L   25  75
5   fund2   L   35  75
```

However, I'd guess that the merging is not necessary and can be obtained directly in apply

Comment: hmm when i run in my local notebook i get `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1` but when i run in the repl i provided, there are no errors but also no new column.

Comment: if i simplify to remove the merge, i see a series with 2 rows.. which is good! just need it to return a full series.. will try to figure out why my join fails with that error

Comment: in your recent code (on repl.it) just run `pd.merge(f, x, on="fund_id")` which gives the desired output. I just ran it there. No error is raised